# Vue Preloader Epic Spinner and the content load at the same time (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js

i want to load preloader first before the content display, However when i install the library of https://epic-spinners.epicmax.co/ . it shows the preloader but it didnt load first. the content and the preloader at the same time. can i ask how can i load the preloader first then show the content after its loaded? Thank you.

Here is the code:

Can also access the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-tdd-ygd4s?file=/src/App.vue:0-714

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <scaling-squares-spinner
      :animation-duration="1250"
      :size="65"
      color="#ff1d5e"
    />
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import { ScalingSquaresSpinner } from "epic-spinners";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    ScalingSquaresSpinner,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo has no conditional rendering at all, so the spinner will always show.

To use that spinner component in `App.vue`, apply a data property (initially set to `true`) that is later set to `false` when the app is ready.

1. Declare a data property (named `"loading"`) with a default of `true`.
2. Use `v-if="loading"` on the spinner element in the template, and `v-else` on the content.
3. When your app is no longer busy, set `loading` to `false` to hide the spinner and show the content.

```html
<template>
  <scaling-squares-spinner v-if="loading"2️⃣ />
  <template v-else2️⃣>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" />
  </template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true 1️⃣
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
     await longRunningTask()
     this.loading = false 3️⃣
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/showing-spinner-in-app-ypwdq?file=/src/App.vue)